# OpenCV Template Matching

Tags: image, templates, image-processing, opencv, match

I am preparing a sample by using OpenCV cvMatchTemplate(); function and I want to find all templates that's max. loc. upper than 0.40 with CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED method.

I mean I want to find all templates which match. I find only the best match template but I want to find all of them.

I hope I explained what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I understand it.

cvMatchTemplate(src1,src2,resultImg,CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

We get each pixel of Result Matris(resultImg) and find maximum white pixels' locations.

So we find other templates.